# Jmeter : Extract multiple variables after send GET request

Tags: variables, jmeter, response

I send a request with JMeter. Then i get the response like this :

```
 [
    {
        "jobId": "00053b3d-c4fa-498b-9ef0-cbf5430e9c61",
        "timer": null,
        "aln": "199430",
        "callerId": "21c48f75-752e-43cf-9d4f-48da62646e98",
        "start": "2019-10-11 04:17:41.900",
        "status": "InProgress",
        "end": null
    },
    {
        "jobId": "001bb8c5-2e7f-4519-beb0-a5bc1bc5cf8d",
        "timer": null,
        "aln": "198049",
        "callerId": "21c48f75-752e-43cf-9d4f-48da62646e98",
        "start": "2019-10-11 04:39:02.736",
        "status": "InProgress",
        "end": null
    },
    {
        "jobId": "00502f22-3e9d-4003-b1f1-1860b613d22e",
        "timer": null,
        "aln": "199362",
        "callerId": "21c48f75-752e-43cf-9d4f-48da62646e98",
        "start": "2019-10-11 04:17:23.124",
        "status": "InProgress",
        "end": null
    },

......

    {
        "jobId": "fffa8b38-9e29-4d48-a540-9fb69f505df3",
        "timer": null,
        "aln": "198016",
        "callerId": "21c48f75-752e-43cf-9d4f-48da62646e98",
        "start": "2019-10-11 04:38:59.454",
        "status": "InProgress",
        "end": null
    }
]
```

I want to get all the jobID and put it into a csv file. I found some guide to extract variable of one response, but how to get all variables like in my case ?
Thanks for your help

I've tried :
Xpath extractor + json path plugin

Comment: Can you paste the full Response?

Comment: Hi @SAIR, it has like 2k+ jobs with the same amount jobid... and why you need a full response ? I will add more but full is not possible...

Comment: That's ok, but i need a valid JSON object, you can include couple of jobid, but with full valid JSON Structure. Because JSON Path Expression will depend on what is your JSON structure is?

Comment: I have provided the answer, try that.

Answer (score 0):

To extract and write all jobID into the CSV file, do the following:

1. Add a JSON Extractor Post Processor as a child of the Request returning the Response. Use `$..jobId` as a Path Expression and `Match No. -1` to capture all matches
2. Add a JSR223 Sampler after the Request and put the following code in Script area:

   ```
   int jobLength = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("jobId_matchNr"));

   String[] responseArray = new String[jobLength];
   for (int i = 0; i < jobLength; i++) {
       responseArray[i] = vars.get("jobId_"+(i+1));
   }

   PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File("test.csv"));
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

   for (String str : responseArray) {
       sb.append(str);
       sb.append('\n');
   }

   writer.write(sb.toString());
   writer.close();
   ```
3. All your JobID will be written into `"test.csv"` file

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns the above JSON
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).each {job ->
       new File('jobs.txt') << job.jobId << System.getProperty('line.separator')
   }
   ```
3. That's it, you will get job IDs saved into `jobs.txt` file, each ID on a new line like:

   ```
   00053b3d-c4fa-498b-9ef0-cbf5430e9c61
   001bb8c5-2e7f-4519-beb0-a5bc1bc5cf8d
   00502f22-3e9d-4003-b1f1-1860b613d22e
   fffa8b38-9e29-4d48-a540-9fb69f505df3
   ```

More information:

- [JsonSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)
- [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)